# Why is my Oozie installation failing?

Tags: hadoop, installation, oozie

I'm trying to install Apache Oozie on my local machine (Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.3) but receive a "java.net.ConnectException Connection refused" error when checking the status of the installation.

**$ oozied.sh start**

```
Setting OOZIE_HOME:          /Users/akirna/oozie
Setting OOZIE_CONFIG:        /Users/akirna/oozie/conf
Sourcing:                    /Users/akirna/oozie/conf/oozie-env.sh
  setting CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx1024m"
Setting OOZIE_CONFIG_FILE:   oozie-site.xml
Setting OOZIE_DATA:          /Users/akirna/oozie/data
Setting OOZIE_LOG:           /Users/akirna/oozie/logs
Setting OOZIE_LOG4J_FILE:    oozie-log4j.properties
Setting OOZIE_LOG4J_RELOAD:  10
Setting OOZIE_HTTP_HOSTNAME: LAMU02T76ZCGTFM.uhc.com
Setting OOZIE_HTTP_PORT:     11000
Setting OOZIE_ADMIN_PORT:     11001
Setting OOZIE_HTTPS_PORT:     11443
Setting OOZIE_BASE_URL:      http://LAMU02T76ZCGTFM.uhc.com:11000/oozie
Setting CATALINA_BASE:       /Users/akirna/oozie/oozie-server
Setting OOZIE_HTTPS_KEYSTORE_FILE:     /Users/akirna/.keystore
Setting OOZIE_HTTPS_KEYSTORE_PASS:     password
Setting OOZIE_INSTANCE_ID:       LAMU02T76ZCGTFM.uhc.com
Setting CATALINA_OUT:        /Users/akirna/oozie/logs/catalina.out
Setting CATALINA_PID:        /Users/akirna/oozie/oozie-server/temp/oozie.pid

Using   CATALINA_OPTS:        -Xmx1024m -Dderby.stream.error.file=/Users/akirna/oozie/logs/derby.log
Adding to CATALINA_OPTS:     -Doozie.home.dir=/Users/akirna/oozie -Doozie.config.dir=/Users/akirna/oozie/conf -Doozie.log.dir=/Users/akirna/oozie/logs -Doozie.data.dir=/Users/akirna/oozie/data -Doozie.instance.id=LAMU02T76ZCGTFM.uhc.com -Doozie.config.file=oozie-site.xml -Doozie.log4j.file=oozie-log4j.properties -Doozie.log4j.reload=10 -Doozie.http.hostname=LAMU02T76ZCGTFM.uhc.com -Doozie.admin.port=11001 -Doozie.http.port=11000 -Doozie.https.port=11443 -Doozie.base.url=http://LAMU02T76ZCGTFM.uhc.com:11000/oozie -Doozie.https.keystore.file=/Users/akirna/.keystore -Doozie.https.keystore.pass=password -Djava.library.path=

Setting up oozie DB
  setting CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx1024m"

Validate DB Connection
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
DONE
DB schema exists

The SQL commands have been written to: /var/folders/bx/5shvx3ln5wx4lp7c7j_l_f65gmq63g/T/ooziedb-4834223640212041380.sql

Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Users/akirna/oozie/oozie-server
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Users/akirna/oozie/oozie-server
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Users/akirna/oozie/oozie-server/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /Users/akirna/oozie/oozie-server/bin/bootstrap.jar
Using CATALINA_PID:    /Users/akirna/oozie/oozie-server/temp/oozie.pid
Existing PID file found during start.
Removing/clearing stale PID file.
```

**$ oozie admin -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -status output**

```
Connection exception has occurred [ java.net.ConnectException Connection refused (Connection refused) ]. Trying after 1 sec. Retry count = 1
Connection exception has occurred [ java.net.ConnectException Connection refused (Connection refused) ]. Trying after 2 sec. Retry count = 2
Connection exception has occurred [ java.net.ConnectException Connection refused (Connection refused) ]. Trying after 4 sec. Retry count = 3
...
```

**oozie/logs/oozie.log output:**

```
******************************************************************************* 
  STARTUP MSG: Oozie BUILD_VERSION [4.3.1] compiled by [akirna] on [2018.04.18-19:11:20GMT]
  STARTUP MSG:       revision [unavailable]@[unavailable]
*******************************************************************************
2018-04-18 22:56:52,077  INFO XLogService:520 - SERVER[] Log4j configuration file [oozie-log4j.properties]
2018-04-18 22:56:52,077  INFO XLogService:520 - SERVER[] Log4j configuration file loaded from [/Users/akirna/oozie/conf]
2018-04-18 22:56:52,077  INFO XLogService:520 - SERVER[] Log4j reload interval [10 sec]
2018-04-18 22:56:52,084  INFO ConfigurationService:520 - SERVER[] Oozie home dir  [/Users/akirna/oozie]
2018-04-18 22:56:52,085  INFO ConfigurationService:520 - SERVER[] Oozie conf dir  [/Users/akirna/oozie/conf]
2018-04-18 22:56:52,085  INFO ConfigurationService:520 - SERVER[] Oozie conf file [oozie-site.xml]
2018-04-18 22:56:52,250  WARN ConfigurationService:523 - SERVER[] Invalid configuration defined, [oozie.service.ProxyUserService.proxyuser.akirna.hosts] 
2018-04-18 22:56:52,251  WARN ConfigurationService:523 - SERVER[] Invalid configuration defined, [oozie.service.ProxyUserService.proxyuser.akirna.groups] 
2018-04-18 22:56:52,254  WARN Services:523 - SERVER[] System ID [oozie-akir] exceeds maximum length [10], trimming
2018-04-18 22:56:52,255  INFO Services:520 - SERVER[] Exiting null Entering NORMAL
2018-04-18 22:56:52,256  INFO Services:520 - SERVER[] Initialized runtime directory [/var/folders/bx/5shvx3ln5wx4lp7c7j_l_f65gmq63g/T/oozie-akir1419795458214876479.dir]
2018-04-18 22:56:52,256  INFO ConfigurationService:520 - SERVER[] Programmatic configuration change, property[oozie.services]=[org.apache.oozie.service.LiteWorkflowAppService, org.apache.oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService]
2018-04-18 22:56:52,258  INFO ConfigurationService:520 - SERVER[] Programmatic configuration change, property[oozie.services.ext]=[]
2018-04-18 22:56:52,274  INFO HadoopAccessorService:520 - SERVER[] JOB_TRACKER_WHITELIST :[], Total entries :0
2018-04-18 22:56:52,274  INFO HadoopAccessorService:520 - SERVER[] NAME_NODE_WHITELIST :[], Total entries :0
2018-04-18 22:56:52,274  INFO HadoopAccessorService:520 - SERVER[] Oozie Kerberos Authentication [disabled]
2018-04-18 22:56:52,458  WARN NativeCodeLoader:60 - SERVER[] Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2018-04-18 22:56:52,556  INFO Services:520 - SERVER[] Initialized
2018-04-18 22:56:52,562  INFO Services:520 - SERVER[] Running with JARs for Hadoop version [3.0.0]
2018-04-18 22:56:52,563  INFO Services:520 - SERVER[] Oozie System ID [oozie-akir] started!
```

**oozie/logs/catalina.out output:**

```
ERROR: Oozie could not be started

REASON: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/permission/AccessControlException

Stacktrace:
-----------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/permission/AccessControlException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2381)
    at org.apache.oozie.util.XConfiguration.getClassByName(XConfiguration.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClasses(Configuration.java:2454)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.ConfigurationService$LogChangesConfiguration.getClasses(ConfigurationService.java:411)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.ConfigurationService.getClasses(ConfigurationService.java:584)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.loadServices(Services.java:288)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.init(Services.java:213)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.ServicesLoader.contextInitialized(ServicesLoader.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4276)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:780)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:676)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:602)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1069)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.permission.AccessControlException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1698)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1544)
    ... 35 more
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: just to double check, the host does have the hadoop client libraries installed?

Comment: By client libraries, do you mean the client code that ships with the Oozie tar or a full install of Hadoop in /usr/local?

Comment: a prereq for oozie is the apache hadoop client jars (https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/DG_QuickStart.html#System_Requirements)

Comment: Yes, I copied all jars from /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.0.0/libexec/share/hadoop to ~/oozie/libext